# $d(a,X) = d(a,\overline{X})$ (distance from point to set is distance from point to closure)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to understand this proof that:

$$d(a,X) = d(a,\overline{X})$$

The proof says:

Since $X\subset \overline{X}$, then $d(a,\overline{X})\leq d(a,X)$. We just need to show that the $<$ from the signal $\leq$ won't hold. For this, we must show that $d(a,\overline{X})< m \implies d(a, X)<m$. Well, if $d(a,\overline{X})< m$, then there exists $\overline{x}\in X$ such that $d(a,\overline{x})<m$. Since $\overline{x}$ is adherent to $X$, there exists $x\in X$ such that $\color{Red}{d(x,\overline{x})<m-d(a,\overline{x})}$. Then, we have:

$$d(a,X)\le d(a,x) \le d(a,\overline{x})+d(\overline{x},x) < d(a,\overline{x})+m-d(a,\overline{x}) = m$$

The question is: where did $\color{Red}{d(x,\overline{x})<m-d(a,\overline{x})}$ came from? I tried to write down a sketch and I ended with:

Suppose a ball $X$. Suppose a point $\overline{x}$ inside it, but very close or in the boundary. Now, a point $a$, out of the ball, such that the distance from $a$ to the set $X$ is $=m$(should be less but let's suppose equality). Now suppose $x\in X$. Then, by triangular inequality, we have:

$$d(x,a) \le d(x,\overline{x})+d(x,a) =  d(x,\overline{x}) + m$$

so we have:

$$d(x,\overline{x}) < m-d(x,a)$$

but it should be

$$d(x,\overline{x}) < m-d(\color{Red}{\overline{x}},a)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$d(x, \bar x)$ can be made as small as you please form some $x\in X$, since $\bar x$ is adherent to $X$. In particular it can be made smaller than $m-d(a,\bar x)$.